# A directory created in shared storage with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT can't be used unless the user consent is asked again with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I am trying to upgrade an app to be copliant with the Android11 shared storage concept. This app needs to store its created gpx files in a storage area not destroyed in case the app is uninstalled. This area shall stay in shared storage and the directory can be created with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setType(DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "AGPS-Tracker");
startActivityForResult(intent, SS_CREATE_GPX_DIR_REQUEST);
```

and in onActivityResult:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
 final   int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
     & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
 getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
 startDirUri = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(uri.getAuthority(),DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(us));
```

Then  I try to use startDirUri  :

```
    uriDir = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(startDirUri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(startDirUri));
```

*I get:  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAGPS-Tracker%20(11)/document/primary%3AAGPS-Tracker%20(11)/children from pid=7209, uid=10341 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs*

Then if  I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE on this new created directory, finally I get the access.

My question is: why  a directory created by the user can't be immediately used? Really we need to ask twice the user: first to create and then to use the same directory?

Comment: `intent.setType(DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR)` Dont do that. Its not intended for directories. Its intended for file types. That it 'works' is an error. What you do has been reported before.

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);` All those flags make no sense. Never. This abuse has been done before too.

Comment: If creating a directory with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT and intent.setType(DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR) is an error then how should we create a directory for files that are not Media, in shared storage?

Comment: You use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. During that action the use can create directories and choose them. If you only choose a directory then after onActivityResult you can create subdirectories in the choosen directory. Or files.

Comment: I understand only now that ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE can create a directory and allow the user to get access permission to the user. Thanks.